tailwind postion element at bottom of screen with margins
I am trying to place a div at the bottom right corner of my screen with margin of 10px right, 10px bottom.
I tried the div code below. It does place the div at bottom right of screen but does not allow me to add margin to it.
I also want to to keep the div at the bottom right. i.e if its a long page and the user scrolls to the bottom of page, it will always remain fixed at the bottom right.
<center>
    <h1 class="text-green-600 text-5xl font-bold">
        GeeksforGeeks
    </h1>
    <b>Tailwind CSS Position Class</b>
    <div class="static text-left p-2 m-2 bg-green-200 h-48">
        <p class="font-bold">Static parent</p>


        <div class="absolute bottom-0 right-0 p-2  mb-10
                    bg-green-500">

            <p>Absolute child</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</center>

UPDATE;
I tried following the advice of @justanotherpeter but it does not work. The div rides up to the top of the screen.

Below is the full code for the above image.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href=
              "https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="text-center">
<center>
    <h1 class="text-green-600 text-5xl font-bold">
        GeeksforGeeks
    </h1>
    <b>Tailwind CSS Position Class</b>
    <div class="static text-left p-2 m-2 bg-green-200 h-[200vh]">
        <p class="font-bold">Static parent</p>
        <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 p-2 bg-green-500">
            <p>Absolute child</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed bottom-[10px] right-[10px] p-2 bg-green-500">
        <p>Fixed positioned div</p>
    </div>
</center>

</body>

</html>


try class="fixed bottom-2 right-2"

The problem happens because your code is using custom style and this code use generated styles from <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">. You can follow two ways.
Use only the tailwind classes without custom styles as example code bellow. Or choose a way to install the Tailwind for your project follow the documentation.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="text-center">
  <h1 class="text-green-600 text-5xl font-bold">
      GeeksforGeeks
  </h1>
  <b>Tailwind CSS Position Class</b>
  <div class="static text-left p-2 m-2 bg-green-200 h-screen">
      <p class="font-bold">Static parent</p>
      <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 p-2 bg-green-500">
          <p>Absolute child</p>
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="fixed bottom-0 right-0 p-2 bg-green-500">
      <p>Fixed positioned div</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




To position a div at the bottom right corner of the screen with a margin of 10 pixels from the right and bottom edges, you should use the fixed positioning class in Tailwind CSS. This will ensure that the div remains fixed in that position even when the user scrolls.
Tailwind playground

hi. it did not work. i can see that it works in the playground. but when i tried it on the page it ride to middle of screen. I have updated my question  and included my full code plus an image of what happened.
